# Integrar Mercado Pago a Android (java)

Tags: android, mercadopago

Siguiendo la documentación oficial de MP (https://mercadopago.github.io/px-android/v3.html) he añadido la siguiente linea de codigo en el archivo build.gradle.kts (app)

```
implementation ("com.mercadopago:sdk:3.8.0")
```

y el error que me arroja es el siguiente

```
Failed to resolve: com.mercadopago:sdk:3.8.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
```

Me estará faltando un repositorio en el build.gradle del proyecto?

Agradezco mucho la ayuda!

Comment: En el ejemplo dice `compile`, probaste escribirlo así?

Comment: El compile esta obsoleto hace varias versiones de Android y Android Studio para nuevos proyectos.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la documentación indica agregar la dependencia a tu proyecto de esta forma:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.mercadopago:sdk:3.8.0'
}
```

en realidad el uso de `compile` es obsoleto, deberías usar `implementation`.

---

En el caso de una proyecto android, debes agregar la dependencia dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` ubicado en el directorio `/app`

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.mercadopago:sdk:3.8.0'
}
```

Si usas un archivo `build.gradle.kts` debes definir de esta forma la dependencia:

```
dependencies {                              
    implementation("com.mercadopago:sdk:3.8.0")
}
```

Si tienes registrada la dependencia y obtienes el error:

> Failed to resolve: com.mercadopago:sdk:3.8.0

probablemente, no tienes conexión a internet o tienes activado el modo offline, al activar la opción "gradle", revisa que no tengas activado el modo offline, que indico en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]